# how to redirect user from login to dashboard REACTJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to redirect to my user-dashboard page after the user is successfully logged in.
I've already tried using push('/dashboard') but even if the credentials were false it redirect to the dashboard page any help please !
So I want when I submit the email and the password correct to login, it will be redirected to the dashboard
How can i add a condition to test if the user is really authenticated ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Authentification.css";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../actions/authActions";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import axios from "axios";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors: {}
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }
  onSubmit = e => {e.preventDefault();
    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    this.props.loginUser(userData);
    this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
  };
render() {
    return (
      <div className="hero">
            <div className="form-box-login">
            <img src={logo} className="image"></img>

                <h1 className="styledh1">LOGIN</h1>
                <form className="input-group">
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input type="email"
                     name="email"
                     value={this.state.email}
                     onChange={this.handleChange}
                      placeholder="Email" className="input-field"/>
                    <input type="password" 
                     name="password"
                     label="Password"
                     value={this.state.password}
                     onChange={this.handleChange}
                     placeholder="Password" className="input-field"
                     />
                    <p className="forgot-password">Forgot your password?</p>
                    <button type="submit" className="submit-btn">LOGIN</button>
                    </form>
                  
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  error: state.error
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {loginUser})(Login);
```

Comment: Hi, have you looked into using a privateRoute ? i would highly suggest you look into it.  https://medium.com/@thanhbinh.tran93/private-route-public-route-and-restricted-route-with-react-router-d50b27c15f5e#:~:text=full%20source%20code-,Private%20Route,function%20separately%20in%20utils%20folder.

Comment: Hello , thank u for ur suggestion but it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

The function responsible for authorization (`loginUser`) is the place where you get your response from server and manage your React app's behaviour. Since it is at `Login`'s parent, you either have to pass some notification down to `Login` whenever user gets authenticated, thru props OR (and it's the preferable way to do it, necessary if it's not a very small app) set the `redux` store's state accordingly (something like `authenticated: true`).

Now, when you have your `authenticated` prop in `Login` component (passed either by parent locally or by redux globally), you can render conditionally:

```
render() {
    if (!this.props.authenticated) 
        return (<Redirect to='/dashboard'/>);
    else
        return (
            //your Login jsx
        )
}
```